# On restarting Hazelcast oldest node, it does not join the cluster

Tags: java, hazelcast

I started first hazelcast embedded server on machine A. This server does not have ip address configured for any other member (since it is first server to start).
I started second hazelcast embedded server on machine B with cluster member configured as A's hazelcast address. They both form a cluster (lets say cluster1) successfully.
Now, I restarted machine A's hazelcast (again without giving any other member IP address as it was in first case). It does not join the existing cluster cluster1.
I am not sure, is this expected? My thinking is that since B used to know about A, it might heartbeat A and when A is up, include it in cluster (or merge)? Is there any setting that can be applied here to attain this?  Should split-brain handling not consider it?
Obviously, if I restart A with B's address, it will form the cluster but I want to explore any other solutions here.

Thanks.

```
            Config config = new Config();
            JoinConfig join = config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin();
            join.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
            String clusterMember = <>;//"" for A and A's hazelcast address for B.
            if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(clusterMember))
               join.getTcpIpConfig().addMember(clusterMember);
            join.getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true);
            server = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

Expected: A should join cluster on restart.
Actual: A did not join cluster on restart

Comment: With the settings above, serverA can't contact the cluster on startup. And the cluster won't send "heartbeats" to serverA after serverA has disconnected. So on startup, serverA will form its own cluster and wait for other servers to join. You can either enable multicast discovery; or set up any other cluster discovery mechanism (see https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#discovery-mechanisms ?)

Comment: Ok but if lets say server A network gets disconnected from server B network and then reconnected, would not that form the cluster again (since sever B has server A mentioned as a member)? How is it different from restart scenario?

Comment: Uhm, I would need to go through the reference manual really; but the cluster composition is not *permanent*; clients can normally come and go, and it makes sense that the cluster does NOT try re-contacting all of them, all the time (it would be a waste of resources- eg. if a cluster runs for months, you can have a large history of clients). Instead, every server (client) must contact the cluster at startup. As soon as it connect to the first server, it is then sent the whole cluster composition.

Comment: I think I got it. It is currently a limitation of hazlecast.
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/8653